# DevExpress XtraTreeList DragDrop

Tags: devexpress, xtratreelist

I am looking for a tutorial to build Drag-Drop of Node **inside same treeist** with DevExpress XtraTreeList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the TreeList's OptionsBehavior.DragNodes property to true.  This will force the TreeList to support drag&drop nodes mode automatically.  If by any reason this mode does not meet your requirements, please let me know why.  I will try to help you.

Comment: I did 'treeList.OptionsBehavior.DragNodes = true;
                treeList.AllowDrop = true;' but won;t work. My treelist is in a continer. Is tht why ?

Comment: Should be able to drag the node on click just by setting OptionsBehaviour.DragNodes to true ? My debugger won't go to treeList1_GiveFeedback .

Comment: Yes, it works in my tests and it is necessary to set the OptionsBehavior.DragNodes property to true.  Try to drag a node by a node indicator.  Also, try to set the SettingsBehavior.Editable to false.  Does it work?